# Cant delete LSCache

Tags: prestashop, litespeed

for very first time I have problem like that.

I tried to make staging envirioment with Prestashop 1.6 which production server use Litespeed Ent. with LSCache. My staging use openlitespeed, but on document I have litespeed-cache: hit - so it's working.

After problems with CSS, Unexpected char with ESI Block I decided to uninstall module. What I did:

1. Purged All Pages, Entire Cache Storage,
2. Disable cache system in module,
3. Disable module (I got info about .htaccess modyfication)
4. Checked .htaccess
5. Checked /tmp/lscache dir - doesn't exist

After that, I have same problem - on homepage, many products I can see ESI block at the begining  document and info cache: hit it means still working...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PrestaShop on OpenLiteSpeed but it will not work with cache since OLS doesn't support ESI. For the OLS case, the default cache folder is located `/usr/local/lsws/cachedata/`, please try to remove the folder and restart the web server.